# Incrementar valor no nome de uma função

Tags: php, funções

Boa tarde, galera! 
Seguinte, tenho três campos de arquivo em uma tabela do meu banco, são eles:
File1, File2 e File3.
Tenho também um get e um set para cada um deles.
A Questão é, queria rodar um for() e em cada loop incrementar o get.

```
    <?php if(isset($pedido) && $pedido->getFile1() != null): ?>
     <?php for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++): ?>
        <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo '/files/'.$pedido->getFile[$i](); ?>">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
                    <strong>
                    Arquivo <?php echo $i; ?>
                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                    </strong>
                </a>
                <br />
                <p>
                    <?php echo $pedido->getFile[i](); ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
     <?php endfor; ?> 
 <?php else: ?>
```

ou seja, em cada incremento ficaria getFile1(), getFile2, getFile3.
Teria alguma forma de fazer isso?
Sei que aquela sintaxe [$i] ali não funciona, foi mais para exemplificar.

Comment: É tão grande a diferença desses `gets`? baseado pelo nome uso bastaria.

Comment: Não, são todos iguais, sou novo em php desculpa se a pergunta é muito ridícula.Como assim "pelo nome uso bastaria"?

Comment: Mas você tem várias funções de `getFile` todas numeradas ? E são todas iguais/similares ? Então significa que não tem as coisas estruturadas corretamente e precisa de refatorar o seu código. Crie uma função `getFile` que receba o numero como parametro e aplique somente as diferenças lá dentro

Answer (score 0):

Conheço as seguintes maneiras de fazer isso:

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++): ?>
    $nomeMetodo = 'getFile' . $i;

    // 1
    $this->{$nomeMetodo}($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
    // 2
    $this->$nomeMetodo($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
    // 3
    call_user_func_array(array('namespaceComNomeDaClasse', $nomeMetodo), array($arg1, $arg2, $arg3));

<?php endfor; ?>
```